# Missing repository class - Symfony v4.25

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Symfony and in one of my entity classes, I faced a problem with missing the repository class. I have a Booking class with a repository class named BookingRepository.

```
class BookingRepository extends EntityRepository
```

Also, I have developed many functions in this Repo class and was working about two days ago.
Now, I don't know why the Booking class does not know the BookingRepository class as a repository.
What happened for my code?

Comment: I would suggest updating your question with a list of the things you tried after searching for 'missing repository class'.  Saves wasting time guessing.

Comment: Check class name + namespace of the repository class and make sure, that it was imported (`use Namespace/Of/BookingRepository`) properly.